# How do you log all the compiler options being used by Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Gradle 7.4.2. I'm trying to see what it uses for `generatedSourceOutputDirectory` (among other `CompileOptions`.

I've tried:

```
tasks.compileJava {
    println(options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory.toString())
}
```

but this prints an unhelpful:

```
task ':lib:compileJava' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'
```

Sleuthing around the code itself on Github, I see that's its defaults are (seemingly) mangaged via XML [code here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/96e5b88f58c263209e83719fba13034c18d99bfb/subprojects/docs/src/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.xml#L85).

How can I see what the current compile options are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option [generatedSourceOutputDirectory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:generatedSourceOutputDirectory) is of type [DirectoryProperty](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty.html); therefore, to get the value that it holds, you need to call [get()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#get--).